# Toolbar moved up

Tags: java, android

Toolbar moved up

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCXYs.png]

How to make a normal?

And how to make transparent toolbar ? I use drawer by mike penz and tabs
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <su.gamepoint.opendomofon.pro.sliding.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: may be you use Full screen theme .

Comment: @Андрей Ужегов if you use my drawer why do you have a `DrawerLayout` defined in your layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways.

Firstly by `xml`: You can set different dimens for different API level and set padding in your `AppBar`.

Secondly by java: Create a method like below

```
 public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

then in your `onCreate()` :

```
   set this padding on your Appbar.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

android:fitsSystemWindows attribute to adjust view layout based on system windows such as the status bar. If true, adjusts the padding of this view to leave space for the system windows. Will only take effect if this view is in a non-embedded activity.

Either you can remove this line or set it to **false**

Comment: did you programetically give any thing regarding systemWindow?